# How does this method call work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am using `PDFKit` in NodeJS to add some images to a PDF document. One of the examples is this:

```
# Fit the image within the dimensions
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 320, 15, fit: [100, 100])
   .rect(320, 15, 100, 100)
   .stroke()
   .text('Fit', 320, 0)
```

I am using pure JS instead of coffeescript and I do not understand how the first line works. How's a key-value pair being passed in as the argument and what'd be the JS equivalent?

Docs here: http://pdfkit.org/docs/images.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's the javascript equivalent

```
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 320, 15, {
  fit: [100, 100]
}).rect(320, 15, 100, 100).stroke().text('Fit', 320, 0);
```

coffee objects don't need curly brackets in many cases. check out http://js2.coffee/ to convert back and forth between coffee and vanilla javascript